# why I cannot access Object's properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm new a newbie to JavaScript and typescipt. Below is my code:

```
let myObj:Object = { foo: 'bar' };
let strVar:string = myObj.foo; // then it throw an error that "property foo does not exist on type 'Object'"
```

So why I cannot access Object's properties?

Comment: This is not a javascript error. Error is caused by typescript. This error will be eliminated when you properly set the type of myObj. Refer Fullstack Guy's answer.

Comment: You can just omit the type to let the compiler infer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is true as the `foo` is not a property of the `Object` type. You need make the following change:

```
let myObj:{ foo: string } = { foo: 'bar' };
let strVar:string = myObj.foo;
```

You can also declare an interface:

```
interface MyObject {
    foo: string;
}

let myObj: MyObject = { foo: "bar" };
let strVar:string = myObj.foo;
```